# I have made a register/sign in page with a radio button to choose if you want to register or log in, but div only changes when you click

Tags: javascript, html, css, radio-button

So I have made it so the div below the radio will change if you change the radio button, but the div only appears when you click and on default, when you open the page it is just empty. You can only see register or log in page if you switch the radio.
How can I make it so by default, when the page is opened there is the register page

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/PaprikaLeves/pen/dydGvPW

Code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="hu">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Elfbar bolt</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
      var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
      var targetBox = $("." + inputValue);
      $(".box").not(targetBox).hide();
      $(targetBox).show();
  });
});
</script>

<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lilita+One&display=swap');
</style>

<div class="magassagg"></div>

<div class="row">

<div class="col-4">
<p></p>
</div>

<div class="col-4 sidebarr">

<div class="segmented-control">
  
<input type="radio" name="radio2" value="reg" id="tab-1" checked="checked"/>
<label for="tab-1" class= "segmented-control__1">
  <p>Register</p></label>

<input type="radio" name="radio2" value="bel" id="tab-2" />
<label for="tab-2" class= "segmented-control__2">
  <p>Log in</p></label>

<div class="segmented-control__color"></div>
</div>


<div class="reg box">This will be the REGISTER page</div>

<div class="bel box">This will be the LOG IN page</div>


</div>

<div class="col-4">
<p></p>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
:root {
--primary-light: #8abdff;
--primary: #6d5dfc;
--primary-dark: #5b0eeb;
--white: #fff;
--greyLight-1: #e4ebf5;
--greyLight-2: #c8d0e7;
--greyLight-3: #bec8e4;
--greyDark: #9baacf;
}


$shadow: .3rem .3rem .6rem var(--greyLight-2), 
-.2rem -.2rem .5rem var(--white);
$inner-shadow: inset .2rem .2rem .5rem var(--greyLight-2), 
inset -.2rem -.2rem .5rem var(--white);

*, *::before, *::after {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: inherit;
}  

.segmented-control {
margin: auto;
grid-column: 3 / 4;
grid-row: 1 / 2;
width: 90%;
height: 4rem;
box-shadow: .3rem .3rem .6rem var(--greyLight-2), 
-.2rem -.2rem .5rem var(--white);;
border-radius: 1rem;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
position: relative;
}

#tab-1:checked ~ .segmented-control__color {
transform: translateX(0);
transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
}

#tab-2:checked ~ .segmented-control__color {
transform: translateX(16.5rem);
transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1);
}

.segmented-control__1 {
width: 48%;
height: 3.6rem;
font-size: 1.4rem;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
cursor: pointer;
color: var(--greyDark);
transition: all .5s ease;
}

.segmented-control__2 {
width: 48%;
height: 3.6rem;
font-size: 1.4rem;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
cursor: pointer;
color: var(--greyDark);
transition: all .5s ease;
}

.segmented-control__color {
position: absolute;
height: 3.4rem;
width: 48%;
margin-left: .3rem;
border-radius: .8rem;
box-shadow: inset .2rem .2rem .5rem var(--greyLight-2), 
inset -.2rem -.2rem .5rem var(--white);;
pointer-events: none;
}

input { display: none; }

input:checked + label {
transition: all .5s ease;
color: var(--primary);
}

input:not(:checked) + label {
transition: all .5s ease;
color: var(--greyDark);
}

input:not(:checked):hover + label {
transition: all .5s ease;
color: var(--primary);
}

.segmented-control__1, .segmented-control__2:hover { color: var(--primary); }

.reg {

}

.bel {

}

.box {
display: none;
}

.zold {
color: #00c900;
}

.vszurke {
color: #c4c4c4;
}

.kover {
font-weight: bolder;
}

.ar {
padding-top: -40px;
}

p {
line-height: 0px;
}

.sidebarr {
border-radius: 1rem;
box-shadow:.8rem .8rem 1.4rem var(--greyLight-2), 
-.2rem -.2rem 1.8rem var(--white);
padding: 2rem;
margin-top: 50px;
background: #E4EBF5;
}

.d-flex {
background: #E4EBF5;
}

.col {
background: #E4EBF5;
}

.row {
background: #E4EBF5;
}

body {
background: #E4EBF5;
}

html {
background: #E4EBF5;
}

.card {
background: #E4EBF5;
box-shadow:.8rem .8rem 1.4rem var(--greyLight-2), 
-.2rem -.2rem 1.8rem var(--white);
margin: auto;
border-style: none;
border-radius: 1rem;
transition: 300ms;
}



.card:hover {
background: #ebf0f7;
box-shadow: 1rem 1rem 1.4rem var(--greyLight-3), 
-.2rem -.2rem 1.8rem var(--white);
margin: auto;
border-style: none;
border-radius: 1rem;
}



.card-img-top {
border-top-left-radius: 1rem;
border-top-right-radius: 1rem;
border-bottom-left-radius: 0.2rem;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0.2rem;
}

.itemektopbot {
margin-top: 50px;
}

.btn {
width: 8rem;
height: 2.5rem;
border-radius: 0.65rem;
box-shadow: .3rem .3rem .6rem #c8d0e7, 
-.2rem -.2rem .5rem #ffffff;;
justify-self: center;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
cursor: pointer;
transition: .3s ease;
border: none;
font-family: 'Lilita One', cursive;
}

.btn__primary {
grid-column: 1 / 2;
grid-row: 4 / 5;
background: #6d5dfc;
box-shadow:inset .2rem .2rem 1rem #8abdff, 
inset -.2rem -.2rem 1rem #5b0eeb,
.3rem .3rem .6rem #c8d0e7, 
-.2rem -.2rem .5rem #ffffff;;
color: #E4EBF5;
}

.btn:hover { color: #FFFFFF; }
.btn:active {
box-shadow:inset .2rem .2rem 1rem #5b0eeb, 
inset -.2rem -.2rem 1rem #8abdff;
}

.btn.p {
font-size: 1.6rem;
font-family: 'Lilita One', cursive;
}

.form {
grid-column: 3 / 4;
grid-row: 3 / 4;
}

.form__input {
width: 20.4rem;
height: 4rem;
border: none;
border-radius: 1rem;
font-size: 1.4rem;
padding-left: 1.4rem;
box-shadow: inset .2rem .2rem .5rem var(--greyLight-2), 
inset -.2rem -.2rem .5rem var(--white);;
background: none;
font-family: inherit;
color: var(--greyDark);
}

.form__input::placeholder { color: var(--greyLight-3);}
.form__input:focus { outline: none; box-shadow:  .3rem .3rem .6rem var(--greyLight-2), 
-.2rem -.2rem .5rem var(--white);; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call `$('.reg').show() ;` on load.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$('.reg').show() ;
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much @user17517503. Can I get one more help? I want to make it so the div fades to the other.... How could I do that because CSS tranform doesn't work

Comment: You can use fadeIn() and fadeOut() function instead of show() and hide().. Specify speed if you want to fadeIn Or fadeOut slow like fadeIn(2000) or fadeOut(2000)..

Comment: there is another bug. I put there a form but it doesn't show up... The form is like this: <div class="form">
      <input type="text" class="form__input" placeholder="Jelszó">
    </div>

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="hu">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Elfbar bolt</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
      var inputValue = $(this).attr("value");
      var targetBox = $("." + inputValue);
      $(".box").not(targetBox).hide();
      $(targetBox).show();
  });
  var inputValue = $('input[type=radio]:checked').attr("value")
  var targetBox = $("." + inputValue);
  $(".box").not(targetBox).hide();
  $(targetBox).show();
});
</script>

<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lilita+One&display=swap');
</style>

<div class="magassagg"></div>

<div class="row">

<div class="col-4">
<p></p>
</div>

<div class="col-4 sidebarr">

<div class="segmented-control">
  
<input type="radio" name="radio2" value="reg" id="tab-1" checked="checked"/>
<label for="tab-1" class= "segmented-control__1">
  <p>Register</p></label>

<input type="radio" name="radio2" value="bel" id="tab-2" />
<label for="tab-2" class= "segmented-control__2">
  <p>Log in</p></label>

<div class="segmented-control__color"></div>
</div>


<div class="reg box">This will be the REGISTER page</div>

<div class="bel box">This will be the LOG IN page</div>


</div>

<div class="col-4">
<p></p>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you help me make it so it is fading away? CSS transition doesn't work for me

Comment: You can set classes (and for the classes associate the fadeing)